# Missing Ubuntu boot options

Tags: dual-boot, windows, bios

I recently installed Ubuntu alongside Windows and I went into the boot manager (pressing F2 on computer startup) and accidentaly loaded the default settings. This removed Ubuntu from the list of boot options and now I can't boot Ubuntu and grub does not load at startup. How can I fix this?

Comment: Exactly what "boot manager" was that where you accidentally loaded the default settings?

Comment: What I meant by "boot manager" is what you get when the computer's starting up and you press F1, F12, etc.

Comment: So, what's preventing you to change it back to the correct boot device? Or is it a UEFI system?

Comment: I can check again, but the "ubuntu" entry that was there when I first loaded the manager completely went away after I loaded defaults. I don't know what a UEFI system is. I'm pretty new to this stuff, so bear with me.

Comment: I think it's UEFI. It says "UEFI BIOS Version: JFET47WW(1.24)"

Comment: It is UEFI and if the Windows is still the one factory installed then surely Windows was installed with that mode. Ubuntu seems to have been correctly installed because the dual boot was working. There are a few methods to get it back:

Comment: You may still have the files required for booting Ubuntu. If so, depending on the UEFI you may try to use the boot from file option and/or manually create a new boot entry pointing to it. Perhaps easier to just use Boot-Repair: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: That seemed to fix it (boot-repair). Thank you!